# Fetch not sending Authorization header in ios

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I use two fetch functions, one to log in another get data from my API.

login works fine but the second fetch throws an error in ios. it works fine on android

Authorization header is not being sent from ios

this is my code:

```
import { Alert } from 'react-native';
import { rootUrl } from './index';
import { translate } from '../../config/translation';
import store from './../store';
import NavigatorService from '../../config/navigator';

export default function fetchTree(Authorization) {
  fetch(`${rootUrl}/tree`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      store.dispatch({ type: 'loading', payload: false });
      if (response.status !== 200) {
        Alert.alert(
          translate('Access Denied'),
          translate('You are not Authorized to view this content'),
          [{ text: translate('OK') }],
          {
            cancelable: false,
          },
        );
        return 0;
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((responseJson) => {
      if (responseJson !== 0) {
        const tree = responseJson[0].tree;
        NavigatorService.reset('Home', { tree });
      }
    });
}
```

this is the response I get from the server:

[image]

**Solution:**

The URL needs a trailing /

So it should have been `${rootUrl}/tree/` instead of `${rootUrl}/tree`

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: I did the same mistake with a Django backend. Django need them slashes...

Comment: Can you check if you get a 3xx first? Auth header is stripped on redirect. If so then I can help you with that. I just figured it out

Answer (score 0):

iOS has reserved HTTP-headers which you cannot use, and Authorization is one of them.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest

See this stackoverflow comment:
[React Native iOS does not add Authorization header, works on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74483940/react-native-ios-does-not-add-authorization-header-works-on-android)

Answer (score -1):

based on react native

[documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html)
**fetch** will work for IOS & Android 
so i don't think the error on fetch i think there is  another error 
 did you add network permission in your **info.plist**

Comment: i even tried with: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict>