# React Native iOS does not add Authorization header, works on Android

Tags: react-native

I'm having an issue where the `Authorization` header is not being added to the request on iOS, it works on Android.

At first I thougt it was `axios`, the http client, but then I switched to just using `fetch` to try things out, still didn't work.

In a screen there is a handler to send a message:

```js
const handleSendPress = async () => {
  await postContact(textInput);
}
```

And the request function:

```js
export const postContact = async (message: string) => {
  // await axiosInstance.post(`${API_URL}/contact`, {
  //   message,
  // });
  await fetch(`${API_URL}/contact`, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
      message,
    }),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      Authorization: 'Bearer [JWT TOKEN]',
    },
  });
};
```

where I commented out `axios` and hardcoded the `Authorization` header.

This works in Android but fails on iOS where the server complains about there being no `Authorization` header in the request.

I don't get it, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out iOS has some reserved HTTP headers, and `Authorization` is one of them, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest.

*If you set a value for one of these reserved headers, the system may ignore the value you set, or overwrite it with its own value, or simply not send it.*

The key word there being **may**, which is why it would usually fail, but in some cases go through.

There is probably some way to configure this, but I ended up just changing the header I use to `X-Authorization`.

Comment: what if I can't change the header's name? Can I override this iOS behavior? I noticed on a real device it works, only simulator doesn't